# Generate rows in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to use javascript to insert new rows in a table when I click a button .This is the table that I'm using.

```
<table id="POITable" style="width: 120%; border: 4px solid #ddd;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;">Hito</td>
        <td style="width:55%;">Descripcion</td>
        <td style="width:20%;">Tiempo</td>
        <td style="width:15%;">Accion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="latbox" name="latbox[]" style="width:100%;"/></td>
        <td><select name="lngbox[]" id="lngbox" onchange=suma(this.form)>
            <option value="0">Seleccione tiempo</option>
            <option value="7">1 Semana</option>
            <option value="14">2 Semanas</option>
            <option value="30">1 Mes</option>
            </select>
            </td>

        <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="+" onclick="insRow(this)" style="height:25px; width:25px"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="latbox" name="latbox[]" style="width:100%;"/></td>
        <td><select name="lngbox[]" id="lngbox" onchange=suma(this.form)>
            <option value="0">Seleccione tiempo</option>
            <option value="7">1 Semana</option>
            <option value="14">2 Semanas</option>
            <option value="30">1 Mes</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="+" onclick="insRow(this)" style="height:25px; width:25px"/>
        <input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)" style="height:25px; width:25px"/></td>
    </tr>
```

When I click on "" call to a javascript function that create a new row and insert before the row that has the button that I click.

This is the script

```
function insRow(row)
{

    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var new_row = x.rows[2].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    //alert(i);
    //x.appendChild( new_row );
    x.insertBefore( new_row, x.childNodes[i]);

}

 </SCRIPT>
```

In the variable "i" I get the index of the row in which I'm going to insert the new row before.
I have no problem when the index it's a new row generated by the javascript code(i>2) but when I try with a index that make references to the row 1 or 2 (The ones that are static, created in the html), the code put the new row before all the rows and not between them. 
I think that the problem is that the javascript can not move the second index.

Someone know how to move the second row one space to put other row before that?

Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. Need more explanation

Comment: `x.childNodes[i]` is the same reference as `row.parentNode.parentNode`, with a lot more work added to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some mistakes in your code earlier row were added outside tbody also insertBefore was incorrect with 2nd argument being i which was row number. It should be the row element which is correct in below code.

```
function insRow(row){
var x=document.getElementById('POITable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
var new_row = x.rows[2].cloneNode(true);
var len = x.rows.length;
new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp1.id += len;
inp1.value = '';
var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
inp2.id += len;
inp2.value = '';
//alert(i);
//x.appendChild( new_row );
console.log(i);
x.insertBefore( new_row, row.parentNode.parentNode);
```

}

Comment: Thanks you very much, it was very was useful. The only problem is that now, put the row in the index that i click the button.
For example. If i click in the button of the index 2, put the new row in the index 2 and the one on the index 2, are moved to the index 3.
I need that if I click on the button on the index 2, put it i the index 3.