# how to create textboxes on tab press in last textbox in a table and tab press on dynamically created textbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

so i have a form and on tab a new row of (textbox and checkbox) is created and on clicking tab from the dynamically created textbox i should get another row below it and the cursor on the newly created row.(ps.i am new to jquery)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">$(document).ready(function() {
var inputNode = $("<tr><td><input type='text' id='input' name='Medicinename' ></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='Morning'></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='AfterNoon'></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='Evening'></td><td><input  type='text' id='target' /></td></tr><br/>");
$('#btnCreateTxt').focusout(function() {
$("#mytable").append(inputNode);
input.focus();
});
});
</script>

<style>
#mytable{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="abc" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Medical-Report</legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Patient Id </p>
</td>
<td>
<input id="patientid" type="text" name="mytext">
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Doctor Name</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="doctorname">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Patient Name </p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="patientname">
</td>
</tr>
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<u>
<h2>Medicine</h2>
</u>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine Name</td>
<td>Morning</td>
<td>AfterNoon</td>
<td>Evening</td>
<td>Dose</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="Medicinename">
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="On" name="Morning">
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="On" name="AfterNoon">
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="On" name="Evening">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Dose"  id="btnCreateTxt"/>
</td></tr></table>
<input type="button" value="Insert" />
</table>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

medicinename,checkboxes and dose are the rows to be created and on tab click on dose field a new row must be created.

Comment: So you haven't tried it yourself at first. Go through some good tutorial try it out then come and ask for help if needed.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
       var inputNode = $("<tr><td><input type='text' id='input' name='Medicinename' ></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='Morning'></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='AfterNoon'></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='On' name='Evening'></td><td><input  type='text' id='target' /></td></tr><br/>");
 
    $('#btnCreateTxt').focusout(function() {    
$("div").append(inputNode);
       input.focus();    
    });

     });

this is my script i thought it was so lame to share

Comment: Nothing is Lane when you are trying to learn. Please include your attempt in the question.

Comment: Have you tried and inspect any errors that occurs in console?

Comment: the code works fine for inserting row on focusout.the problem is how do i append row from the dynamically created row

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043688/generate-rows-in-a-table-using-javascript/45044134#45044134